# Unexpected results for yaml-cpp comparisons

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Consider the following code (yamltest.cpp):

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string val = "[1, 2, 3]";
  YAML::Node yn0 = YAML::Load(val);
  YAML::Node yn1 = YAML::Load(val);

  std::cout << "===== yn0 =====\n" << yn0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "\n"  << std::endl;
  std::cout << "===== yn1 =====\n\n" << yn1 << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "yn0 == yn0: " << (yn0==yn0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "yn1 == yn1: " << (yn1==yn1) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "yn0 == yn1: " << (yn0==yn1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "yn1 == yn0: " << (yn1==yn0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "YAML::Load(val) == YAML::Load(val): " << (YAML::Load(val)==YAML::Load(val)) << "\n" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "yn0 != yn0: " << (yn0!=yn0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "yn1 != yn1: " << (yn1!=yn1) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "yn0 != yn1: " << (yn0!=yn1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "yn1 != yn0: " << (yn1!=yn0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "YAML::Load(val) != YAML::Load(val): " << (YAML::Load(val)!=YAML::Load(val)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::noboolalpha;

  return 0;
}
```

Along with its associated Makefile:

```
yt:
    g++ -g -Wall yamltest.cpp -o yt -lyaml-cpp

clean:
    rm yt
```

Running it produces the following results:

```
$ ./yt 
===== yn0 =====
[1, 2, 3]


===== yn1 =====
[1, 2, 3]

yn0 == yn0: true
yn1 == yn1: true
yn0 == yn1: false
yn1 == yn0: false
YAML::Load(val) == YAML::Load(val): false

yn0 != yn0: false
yn1 != yn1: false
yn0 != yn1: false
yn1 != yn0: false
YAML::Load(val) != YAML::Load(val): false
```

I expected all of the `==` tests to return `true` and all of the `!=` tests to return `false`, but this is clearly not happening.  So, is this the correct way to compare YAML-CPP objects to test for equivalence?  If not, what is the correct way?

This is running on CentOS 7.x and GCC 9.2.0.

Comment: Since the documentation pretty much does not exist, I had a look at the source and did not find an `operator!=`, which means there is some implicit conversion going on. `operator==` only compares an internal reference, so just tells you, if both Nodes point to the same object (see https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/968e0c1f0281fdaf66d0983bd8bd694263400810/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node.h#L25) Right now, I don't know of a way to compare YAML Nodes other than manually iterating through both graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into [the code](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/b218787b984239c2311b91ac5386e642e94e9095/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h#L460), the `operator==` is testing for identity and not for equality.

```
bool YAML::detail::node::is(const node& rhs) const { return m_pRef == rhs.m_pRef; }
```

Therefore, the `operator==` will return true only if the objects are the same and not if they contain the same value.

For the `operator!=` case, it is a bug (IMHO), the Node is [implicitly converted to bool type](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/b218787b984239c2311b91ac5386e642e94e9095/include/yaml-cpp/node/node.h#L63) with value `unspecified_bool::true_value`. Therefore, the expressions are always false.

Googling a bit, there are open enhancement request for your use case and [some code contributed](https://gist.github.com/kunaltyagi/ebe13098cc22a717f793684659644f4e) to compare for equivalence.